# Image not found when print document using jquery PrintThis

Tags: jquery, image, printthis

I'm print a web page using the jqueryThis plugin.

We are going to print the image and text, but when we are click print button, everything is fine, but still the image is not found on the print page.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```
<?php include("header.php");?>
<br /><br /> 
<li><a href="" onClick="return print_student()" >Print</a></li>
<div class="container " id="print_this" style=" color:black; ">
    <div class="container">
        <img src='images/as.jpg' width='50' height='50' />
    </div> 
    <div class="container">Mohsin Mushtaq</div> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function print_student(){
    $('#print_this').printThis({
        debug: false,
        printContainer:false,
        importCSS: true,
        loadCSS: "http://localhost/erp/css/bootstrap.min.css", 
        canvas: true, 
        base: true,            
        formValues: true,          
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: i think stack overflow fail to ans me

Comment: A. Have you tried `debug: true` and inspected the printThis iframe to see if there are any issues? B. Try a fully qualified url for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add full url within the  tag
example http://domain/path/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

try waiting a moment (500ms or 2000ms for example) until the image can load, using :

```
 $('#divToPrint').printThis({
        printDelay: 2000, // waiting 2 secondes
        importCSS: true,
        importStyle: true,
        loadCSS: true,
        canvas: true
    });
```

as option while calling printThis().